# Magento display shipping costs in cart

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to display the shipping costs in the cart?
Like this:
[Click here for an example!](http://i39.tinypic.com/6oem3k.jpg)

Regards,

Fluxxi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Magento can calculate it, then it can show it. For Magento to calculate shipping, it needs to know the shipping address and shipping method. I was also looking into this recently and found [this](https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping). It didn't work for me because we use custom shipping methods that are very different from the Magento ones, but it might work for you.

Comment: Link is dead  mate please provide another one

Comment: link is dead remove it or provide new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a flat rate for shipping and handling, it is a standard magento feature you can set up in the shipping settings.