# Don't include shipping in total cost displayed in cart

Tags: magento, checkout

To display the total cost of all the items it the customers cart including taxes I use

```
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
```

And it works fine if the user is not logged in. But if the user is logged in then the cost of shipping is added to the total price. How do I avoid that?

Our site only have one shipping option which is a fixed cost. (And it is this price which is added to the total if the user is logged in).

Using magento 1.6.0.0

Comment: offer 0 shipping if you don't need this

Comment: I need a fixed cost shipping. I just don't want to include shipping in the price shown to the user in the cart while he is browsing the website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940702/magento-display-shipping-costs-in-cart/7944031#7944031

Comment: I don't see how that link helps at all. The thing I don't understand is why the result of getGrandTotal() differs depending on if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Not that familiar with magento, but have you looked into getQuote() and getGrandTotal() code for clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartValue = 0;
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $cartValue += $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
}

echo $cartValue;
```

Comment: That will work. It just seems so wrong that I have to add the prices together myself, to get a correct total